# Nullable DateTimes and the AddDays() extension

Tags: c#

I have a DateTime variable that can either be null or a Datetime. I figured a nullable DateTime type would work, but I am getting an error telling me that said

> `Nullable<DateTime>` does not have a definition for AddDays

. Is there any way to resolve this error?

```
DateTime? lastInvite = (DateTime?)Session["LastInviteSent"];

if ((string)Session["InviteNudgeFlag"] == "False" && ((lastInvite == null && DateTime.Now >= AcctCreation.AddDays(7)) || (int)Session["InviteCount"] > 0 && DateTime.Now >= lastInvite.AddDays(7)))
{
   // Non important code here
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should consider trying to make your logic more readable:

```
var inviteNudgeFlag = bool.Parse((string) Session["InviteNudgeFlag"]);

if(!inviteNudgeFlag)
{
    return;
}

var lastInvite = (DateTime?) Session["LastInviteSent"];   
var inviteCount = (int) Session["InviteCount"];
var numOfDays = 7;
var now = DateTime.Now;

var weekSinceLastInvite = lastInvite.HasValue
                            ? now >= lastInvite.Value.AddDays(numOfDays)
                            : now >= AcctCreation.AddDays(numOfDays);

var hasInvites = !lastInvite.HasValue || inviteCount > 0;
var canInvite = hasInvites && weekSinceLastInvite;

if(!canInvite)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Testing it now, but so far, I believe this will work perfectly. You have relieved me of the stress of a whole day of chasing my tail.

Comment: The hasValue and Value on DateTime? types has helped me alot.

Answer (score 46):

You need to go through the "Value" property:

```
lastInvite.Value.AddDays(7)
```

Note that this will throw an exception if the DateTime is actually null. Luckily, there is another property you can use to test for this, "HasValue".

```
if (lastInvite.HasValue){ /* code */ }
```

Answer (score 13):

There are multiple ways to resolve this error.

1. Use `Convert.ToDateTime()` method which handles null datetime values.

   Convert.ToDateTime(lastInvite).AddDays(7);
2. Use `Value` property

   lastInvite.Value.AddDays(7)
3. Use `GetValueOrDefault()` method

   lastInvite.GetValueOrDefault().AddDays(7)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the documentation for the `Nullable<T>` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx), you'll see it only has a few members. The `Value` member will get you the `T` inside, if the `Nullable<T>` container has a value. The `Nullable<T>` doesn't borrow any members from the type `T` it wraps.